# Have auto selected categories with new section entry

Tags: category, content

Is there a way to have auto selected a category when an editor creates a new section entry in the admin?
Kinda like a pre-filled field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That functionality doesn't currently exist out-of-the-box (as of 2.5.2752), but it would be possible as a custom development: You'd essentially need to create a clone of the Categories fieldtype, add your own config/setting to select the default categories, and then use the `prepValue()` method of the fieldtype to pre-select those default categories for new entries.